# Google Calendar API - Unable to set Event Organizer

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar JAVA API. I am able to create an Event with 'hangoutsMeet' option successfully.

Problem : I am not able to set Organizer with API Request.

Default : By Default API Key owner ( From the G Suit account API key has been authorized ) is a Organizer.

If I do not able to set Organizer using API, entire solution of creating Google Event with 'Hangout Meet' video option will not work, as without organizer who will approve the Participant.

I have use following code, however it seems not working. Do I missing anything ?

```
    CreateConferenceRequest createRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
    ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSolutionKey_ = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
    conferenceSolutionKey_.setType("hangoutsMeet");

    createRequest.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSolutionKey_);
    createRequest.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
            new EventAttendee().setEmail("xyz@gmail.com"),
            new EventAttendee().setEmail("pqr@gmail.com"),
            new EventAttendee().setEmail("abc@gmail.com"),
        };

    Organizer organizer = new Organizer();
    organizer.setDisplayName("XYZ");
    organizer.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
    organizer.setSelf(false);
    event_.setOrganizer(organizer);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set an organizer who is **not** the creator itself, you will have to transfer the event to the new organizer's calendar. As you can read in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events):

> *To change the organizer, use the move operation. Read-only, except when importing an event.*

To do so in Java you can use this method:

`Event updateEvent = service.events().move(yourCalendarId, event_.getId(), "xyz@gmail.com").execute();`

Be sure you have the permission to edit the new organizer's event.

### References:

[Event move()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move)